# Number sorting by a recursive function

Tags: python-2.7, recursion

Could anyone help me figure out why my recursive function isn't working?
I am trying to sort a list of numbers so that it would start with the biggest one, and continue in an descending order.

```
def sort(L):
  newlist=[]
  if len(L) == 0:
    return []
  else:
    z = max(L)
    a=newlist.append(z)
    g=L.remove(z)
    return a, sort(g)


print sort([1,5,8,49,29,2])
```

Comment: I encourage you to edit your post and add a proper programming language tag as well as an expected and actual (incorrect) output - that way you will get bore/better answers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

L.remove(z) and newlist.append(z) both return None.
If you want g to be the same as L but without the z element, you could write:

```
g=list(l)
g.remove(z)
```

Also, you are returning multiple return values, when I think you want to return a list. The following seems to work:

```
def sort(L):
  if len(L) == 0:
    return []
  else:
    z = max(L)
    g = list(L)
    g.remove(z)
    return [z] + sort(g)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    s = sort([1,5,8,49,29,2])
    print s
```

Comment: Your correction was helpful. Thank you. It seems that without explicitly stating g=list(L) g wasn't a list or something. I find that weird but then again I am no python expert.

Comment: Actually, if you write g=L then g is a list, but it is the SAME LIST as L. What you really want here is to generate a new list which is identical to L. And this is what we do by g=list(L)

Comment: It's important to realize that the `remove` operation alters the list but doesn't return anything.  Hence it needs to be done on a separate line before passing the modified list to the recursive sort call.

Comment: FWIW, `g=L[:]` is both shorter & faster than calling the `list` constructor.

Comment: Thanks. Didn't know that :-)